# Pagination of feed in facebook group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I access a Facebook Feed, these are the last few lines:

```
"paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/962582957103509/feed?limit=10&since=1420156351&access_token=xxx&__paging_token=enc_AezQonKWxBRti3bfaBZB6neom26Sz9fvsTXspJuJw6sOEoW8HOiTXZ2Ci5PiyeD69-Yfl4n7y4HFrv9wYUlcYVCRTRqz8P9osAFdwmTOq9Ehdg&__previous=1",


      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/962582957103509/feed?limit=10&access_token=xxx&until=1420134308&__paging_token=enc_Aexa_5g1FrfvOTcdIVludEkmqfstBYu3Chbs9WafB00XSu6XCk8zS4kkfaw_97WHy4PLt21BqEidTJ8GpN2ppyGoubteiueuwdycVh_yLLBPjg"
   }
```

These lines have the data for paginating results of a post´s group.

With PHP and `json_decode` I extract it, create two forms for sending this pagination data and get the results of all posts of my group.

```
    if($_REQUEST['action']=="page")
    {

    if($_REQUEST['mode']=="next")
    {
    $url_data_content_group=json_decode(file_get_contents("".$_REQUEST['feednext'].""));
    }

    if($_REQUEST['mode']=="previous")
    {
    $url_data_content_group=json_decode(file_get_contents("".$_REQUEST['feedprevious'].""));
    }


    }
else
{
$url_data_content_group=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$id_group."/feed?access_token=".$access_token."&limit=10"));
}




<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Next Posts">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="page">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="next">
<input type="hidden" name="feednext" value="<?php print "".$url_data_content_group->paging->next."&limit=10";?>">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous Posts">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="page">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="previous">
<input type="hidden" name="feedprevious" value="<?php echo "".$url_data_content_group->paging->previous."&limit=10";?>">
</form>
```

The pagination works perfectly and shows me every 10 results, the problem is when I use the previous pagination, it doesn't show the 10 results (from until). Instead it always send me back to the first posts.

For example if I go for 200 results and push over previous, it doesn't show me 190 results, it shows me the first posts.

I tried many things and always get the same result, I don´t know if it´s problem with the API or I did something wrong

What seems to be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The paging information seems to be broken. File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

For the time being you can use the `until` and `limit` param and keep a reference to the previous time requested

Example

- `&until=1420134308` Page 2
- `&until=1420123958` Page 1

Note: **Your application token was removed from this question, please keep this secret, otherwise someone can have total control over your application**

Comment: And where i get this time i think in dat but when i go the next post i can´t get the until time for this if i get sure i can do this , other thing i think it´s down 3000 entries to file and paginate with php and no call the feed

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you just said.